# Не работает print() в discord.py

Tags: python, print, discord.py

Полностью не работает команда `print()`. Понятия не имею в чем ошибка, могу только сказать, что `print()` не работает только в `@client.event` и `@client.command()`. Если он не входит в их состав, то работает правильно.
Вот код:

````
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from array import *

client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Activity(name='No game No live: Zero', type=discord.ActivityType.watching, details="Kawaii~")
    await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('id'):
        await message.channel.send(
        embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Инфо',
        description=message.channel.id,
        color=message.author.color
        ).set_thumbnail(
        url='https://i.imgur.com/zizM1Qk.jpg'
        ))
        print('123')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def привет(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Привет!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def хелп(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Я бот, да ты и сам знаешь.\n**Мои команды:**\n```!привет - Вывод сообщения с приветом.``` ```!хелп - эта команда.```')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def print(ctx, *, text):
    gg = "".join(text)
    await ctx.send(gg)


client.run('TOKEN')
````

Вот ошибка: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07qwW.png]

Comment: Что значит хм... "не работает"? Не печатает? Ошибки? Также называть переменные/функции русскими буквами — это жесть XD

Comment: Victor VosMottor, а так можно было?)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Я блин новенький, и на этом сайте соорентировался за 5 секунд. Проблема в том, что не печатает в консоль с помощью команды print(). Ошибку я указал выше. И русские буквы там, потому что это команда, а если ты про другое, то скажи. Сам код рабочий, но в консоль с помощью команды print() ничего вывести не могу.

Comment: @LENN, если вы хотите сделать название команды на русском, то это можно делать в декораторе: @client.command(name='привет').

А функции желательно называть на английском :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть команда, которая называется print

```
async def print(ctx, *, text):
    gg = "".join(text)
    await ctx.send(gg)
```

Не стоит называть команды зарезервированными словами

Надо переименовать команду и ошибка уйдет